# command at job that copies all files in home directory within half an hour

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this Question and i try to solve it but i could not . can anyone help me
i am not good with at command when i study it =( the Question :
creating an at job that copies all files in your home directory to /var/tmp within half an hour. You may want to create a sub-directory in /var/tmp. A message will appear to indicate that the copying task is successfully done

Comment: What have you tried so far? People can help you more if you show them your code and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can approach copying a home directory into `/var/tmp/`. Whether or not it completes in 30 minutes will depend on your system; the size your home directory and speed of your disk.

```
cp --archive --verbose "$HOME" /var/tmp/home_backup
```

The `--archive` flag will preserve permissions and ownership, and copy sub directories recursively. If you have `rsync` installed you could use the following:

```
rsync --archive --progress "$HOME"/ /var/tmp/home_backup
```

The main advantage of rsync is that if the copy is interrupted, it can pick up where it left off without recopying files.